# Bar button for all tab bar controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have three view controllers embedded in UITabBarController. Each view controller is embedded in navigation controller.

The logic of my app is to have navigation right bar button on all tab bar view controllers (i.e. "Menu" button which should be seen from each view controller). The easiest way to achieve this is to add this button to all navigation controllers separately. But I think it is not good solution because then the code for this button must be repeated in each navigation controller.

Is there any way to have same navigation right button on all controllers of UITabBarController?

(In my app i'm not using Storyboards)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extension **UIViewController**   create  a navigation bar Method call anywhere  from ViewController  in your project.navigation bar will appear with right button menu .

for example

```
    import UIKit

    extension UIViewController {

        func setupNavigationBar(title: String) {
            // back button without title
            //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""

            //back button color
            //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white

            //set titile
             self.navigationItem.title =  title

            //set text color & font size
            //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.init(red: 251/255, green: 251/255, blue: 251/255, alpha: 1) , NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 19)]

            //set background color without gradian effect
            //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red: 134/255, green: 145/255, blue: 152/255, alpha: 1)

            //show right button 
            let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Menu"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(menu))

            //right Bar Button Item tint color 
            //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 219/255, green: 219/255, blue: 219/255, alpha: 1)

            //show the Menu button item
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

            //show bar button item tint color 
            //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 219/255, green: 219/255, blue: 219/255, alpha: 1)

        }

        func menu(){ 
            print("showSlideOutMane fire ")
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new UIViewController class, that adds a bar button item to its navigation controller's navigation bar ("Menu" for example). Then your other view controllers could inherit from your new UIViewController class. This way, you would have to write the code for adding your bar button only once.

Answer (score 0):

UITabBarController inherits from UIViewController. Tehnicly You can push UITabBarController in UINavigationController. Then inside UITabBarController you can setup UIBarButtonItem.